# puppet - could not find class

Tags: puppet, hiera

so I'd like to think I'm doing something really, really simple and I'm not sure what's going on here.

I'm using the puppet [control-repo](https://github.com/puppetlabs/control-repo) as a baseline.

/manifests/site.pp

```
node default {
  hiera_include('classes')
}
```

/data/common.yaml

```
---
puppet_enterprise::master::code_manager::deploy_pool_size: 4
puppet_enterprise::master::code_manager::timeouts_deploy: 300

classes:
  - profile::base
```

/site/profile/manifests/base.pp

```
class profile::base {
  #the base profile should include component modules that will be on all nodes
  class { 'ntp':
    iburst_enable  => true,
    logfile        => '/var/log/ntp.log',
    package_ensure => 'latest',
    package_manage => true,
    servers        => [ '0.ca.pool.ntp.org', '1.ca.pool.ntp.org', '2.ca.pool.ntp.org', '3.ca.pool.ntp.org' ],
    service_enable => true,
    service_ensure => 'running',
    service_manage => true,
  }

  class { 'java':
    package => 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel',
  }

  class { 'python':
    provider   => 'rhscl',
    ensure     => 'present',
    version    => 'rh-python36',
    dev        => 'present',
    virtualenv => 'present',
  }

  class { 'zabbix::agent':
    manage_repo    => true,
    zabbix_version => 4.0,
    server         => '10.77.1.11',
    agent_use_ip   => true,
  }
}
```

When attempting to do a `puppet agent -t` I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::profile::base for myserver.mydomain.com at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:32:3 on node myserver.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Unable to find the class profile::base suggests that you don't have the file containing that class in the expected locations on the puppet master.

Comment: The default module path does not include a `site/` directory.  If you can confirm that your manifest is indeed present in the specified directory (*relative to the relevant environment directory*), then the problem is likely that you need to [add the `site/` subdirectory to your modulepath](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/dirs_modulepath.html#setting-the-modulepath-and-base-modulepath) by editing the environment's `environment.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you didn't get your control-repo deployed onto master server

Please follow steps described [here](https://github.com/Puppet-RampUpProgram/control-repo) on how to do this: